# Using the Canvas API to determine if an account belongs to a student or not

Tags: php, api, canvas-lms

I am building an app for my school and I had read a little on Canvas's API and was wondering if anyone on here has played with it.

I am trying to make part of my account validation check whether or not a person is a student (and not a teacher/admin/etc.) but can't find a part of the API to help me with this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users in canvas can have multiple roles, that are different based on the context the user is in. For example a user could be a teacher in one course and a student in another. Or a user could be an admin in one account, and not another.

There are two different endpoints you will need to look at to check what roles a user has.

Enrollments:
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/enrollments.html

An enrollment object in canvas will tell you what courses a user is in, and their role in the course.

Admins:
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/admins.html#method.admins.index

The admin endpoint can give you a list of the admins in an account. But you will need an access token that has admin permissions to access this API.